How to test v-text-field rule placeholder's text in v-messages__message?
<v-text-field
    density="compact"
    v-model="textMaterial"
    :rules="textMaterialRules"
    label="Text Material"
></v-text-field>

This is a simple example of how I am using v-text-field in a  with a  at the bottom of type submit which triggers the rule output to be displayed. The rules are defined as:
export default defineComponent({
  data() {
    return {
      textMaterial: '',
      textMaterialRules: [
        (value: string | undefined) => {
          if (value?.length != 0) return true

          return 'An error message.'
        }
      ]
    }
}

This works fine when testing manually. But testing using vitest I am not able to find the element which displays the rule output. Its class seems to be .v-messages__message.
it('displays error message', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Page);
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();

    const submitButton = wrapper.find('v-btn[type="submit"]');
    expect(submitButton.exists()).toBe(true);
    
    await submitButton.trigger('click');
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();

    // TODO: not able to find v-messages__message elements
    // expect(wrapper.find('.v-messages__message').text()).toContain('the error message above.');
});

Any help will be appreciated, I have been stuck on this for so long.
I have tried getting v-form from wrapper.find() and figure out something but nothing good came out of it.
wrapper.html() returns only html with v-form and v-text-field so I am thinking is there no way of getting this rules data from this wrapper and there is something else that I am not aware of to be done to make this text work.
Edit: There are 2 such v-text-fields that I am using on this component so I am using findAll generally.
Use this to replicate: https://github.com/ksushant881/vue-testing-issue

try wrapper.find('.messages__message')

does not work @typed-sigterm

can you create a [mre] for this?

that could take a while, I have provided content of 2 files component.vue which has template and script and other is test, can you tell me where can I provide you more details.
Or if you have a vue project already setup you can add this v-form, v-text-field and a v-btn and the little script and add the same test (test is completely copied)
I was able to find wrapper.find('v-btn[type="submit"]') but not v-messages__message is the only problem and I dont see any documentation around its testing

Is it Vuetify? There is a playground that you could use for a repro.

yes it is vuetify, vite, vitest, vue 3 and typescript project, I am trying to create a minimal github repo to post here but hate the setup process of any js project, not to mention new to JS

Also, I wrote a test of v-tabs in which I used wrapper.find('.v-tab') and it worked, so the prefix being a problem is unlikely to me

https://github.com/ksushant881/vue-testing-issue please use this repo for replication @kissu

The test will not actually render the Vuetify components unless you provide it with a Vuetify instance to resolve the components (Reference).
I modified the example that you provided:
// src/components/__tests__/HelloWorld.spec.ts
import { describe, it, expect } from 'vitest'

import { mount, config } from '@vue/test-utils'
import HelloWorld from '../HelloWorld.vue'

import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'

// Create a vuetify instance with all available components
const vuetify = createVuetify({components, directives});

// This turns off stubs that hide some components
config.global.stubs.transition = false;
config.global.stubs['transition-group'] = false;

describe('HelloWorld', () => {
  it('displays error message', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(HelloWorld, { global: { plugins: [vuetify] } });

    // Notice the change from `v-btn` to `.v-btn`,
    // since all vuetify components will now be rendered correctly
    const submitButton = wrapper.find('.v-btn[type="submit"]');
    expect(submitButton.exists()).toBe(true);
    
    let messages = wrapper.find('.v-messages__message');
    expect(messages.exists()).toBe(false);

    // Triggering 'click' will not actually do anything,
    // since the validation of the v-text-field is tied 
    // to the 'submit' event of the v-form
    await submitButton.trigger('submit');

    // It seems like `await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()` is not needed.

    messages = wrapper.find('.v-messages__message');
    expect(messages.exists()).toBe(true);
    expect(messages.text()).toContain('error message');
});
})

The configuration needed to be adapted, too (Reference).
// vitest.config.js

// ...
export default mergeConfig(
  // ...
  defineConfig({
    test: {
      globals: true, // added
      server: { deps: { inline: ['vuetify'] } }, // added
      // ...
    }
  })
)

